# Laravel 5.3 Slack integration

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I need to get access to Slack's Event API from my Laravel 5.3 application. I have installed [vluzrmos's package from GitHub](https://github.com/vluzrmos/laravel-slack-api), but I can't get it to work properly. I ran through all the steps in the installation, but when I try to do `SlackUser::lists()` in my Controller I get an error like this:

> Non-static method Vluzrmos\SlackApi\Contracts\SlackUser::lists() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.

Could you help? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to inject whatever object you're trying to access through the constructor of the controller (leveraging Laravel's DI)?

Comment: yes, no help using that

Comment: Show us the full controller code

Comment: Extracted the core of the issue, the returned Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have configured the `providers` & `aliases` correctly (in `config/app.php`), you need to add:

```
use SlackUser;
```

to the top of your class, and then call:

```
SlackUser::lists();
```

Please post your usage of `SlackUser::lists();` if this doesn't solve your issue.